# Question on the equal Sylow number

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Let $p$ and $q$ be prime divisors of finite group $G$. Also let $n_{p}$ be
the number of Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ . Is there any example such that
$n_{p}=n_{q}\neq 1$? Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are $33$ such groups of order less than $256$.

Comment: This is hardly a research level question!

Comment: Consider any Frobenius group with nilpotent complement not of prime power order. There are many such groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless I mis-computed, this happens in the group of affine transformations ($x \mapsto ax+b$ with $a\neq 0$) over the field of 7 elements.  There seem to be 7 2-Sylow subgroups and 7 3-Sylow subgroups.

Comment: This is true in groups of affine transformations mod a a prime $l$ more generally, for $p$ and $q$ any two prime divisors of $l-1$. The stabilizer of a $p$ or $q$-Sylow subgroup is the stabilizer of the unique point it fixes.